# Show that $I-A$ is invertible given $A^p=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a $n\times n$ matrix $A$ such that $A^p=0$ (null matrix) for an integer $p>0$

show that $I-A$ is invertible and that $(I-A)^{-1} =I + A + A^2 + ... + A^{p-1}$.

Comment: Can you do $(I-A)(1+A+A^2+\dots+A^{p-1})$? What's the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$I-A$ is invertible if and only if $\ker I-A=\{0\}$.

If $v\in \ker I-A, Av=v$, hence $0=A^pv = v$.

Can you compute $(I-A)(I + A + A^2 + ... + A^{p-1})$ ?